# Unexpected AssertionError: single test not using logged in user from previous step

Tags: python-3.x, flask, authentication, response, pytest

I am following the tutorial by http://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/flask-tutorial/, which I believe is based on https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world. Great stuff for a beginner.

I am getting different results when testing my code through frontend manually (which works fine) v.s. through pytest.

My test tries to show the "groups" endpoint which requires a login (standard @login_required decorator).

- I initially test the user getting a login page ("Knock knock") when trying to get the endpoint without a login. This works manually and through pytest.
- I login a user. If I inspect the response from the login I can clearly see a "Welcome back Pete!" success message.
- My second assert receives a response from URL `/login?next=%2Fgroups` indicating the `/groups` endpoint is called without a login/authentication preceding it and the assert fails. Testing this manually works as expected. Why is that single test not using the same user/session combination in the next step(s)?

**Test with the problem is the first snippet below:**

```
def test_groups(app):
    assert b'Knock knock' in get(app, "/groups").data
    login(app, "pete@testmail.com", "pete123")
    assert b'Test group 1' in get(app, "/groups").data
```

*My "get" function for reference:*

```
def get(app, endpoint: str):
    return app.test_client().get(endpoint, follow_redirects=True)
```

*My "login" function for reference:*

```
def login(app, email="testuser@testmail.com", password="testing"):
    return app.test_client().post('/login', data=dict(email=email, password=password), follow_redirects=True)
```

*The app (from a conftest fixture imported in the test module by @pytest.mark.usefixtures('app')) for reference:*

```
@pytest.fixture
def app():
    """An application for the tests."""
    _app = create_app(DevConfig)
    ctx = _app.test_request_context()
    ctx.push()

    yield _app

    ctx.pop()
```

*The login route for reference:*

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
            if user is not None and user.is_correct_password(form.password.data):
                user.authenticated = True
                user.last_login = user.current_login
                user.current_login = datetime.now()
                user.insert_user()
                login_user(user)
                flash(f'Welcome back {user.name}!', 'success')
                return redirect(url_for('our_awesome_group.index'))
            else:
                flash('Incorrect credentials! Did you already register?', 'error')
        else:
            flash_errors(form)
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

*The groups route for reference:*

```
@app.route('/groups')
@login_required
def groups():
    groups_and_users = dict()
    my_group_uuids = Membership.list_groups_per_user(current_user)
    my_groups = [Group.query.filter_by(uuid=group).first() for group in my_group_uuids]
    for group in my_groups:
        user_uuids_in_group = Membership.list_users_per_group(group)
        users_in_group = [User.query.filter_by(uuid=user).first() for user in user_uuids_in_group]
        groups_and_users[group] = users_in_group
    return render_template('groups.html', groups_and_users=groups_and_users)
```

Comment: I recall the flask docs have a tutorial on testing with pytest and how to login and follow redirects. Have you looked at that part of the docs ?

Comment: @Clint I assume you mean http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/testing/ - yes I've read that. Their client fixture is similar to mine (both are using the `flask.app.test_client()`), they seem to post the same way (using the data `dict`) and the "Logging In and Out"-section has a logout that follows a login in which I presume they implicitly are using the same user.

Comment: Do you make and use the testclient anywhere?  like _app.testclient and passing that in instead of the app function? 


`@pytest.fixture
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()`

Comment: @Clint I think you helped me fix it - creating the testclient in a separate fixture and using that. But I do not understand it? Why does it work? I figure it has something to do with the two asserts creating "different clients" by using the test_client() method on the same flask.app.Flask object twice?

Comment: Got it / understand it: _This client fixture will be called by each individual test. It gives us a simple interface to the application, where we can trigger test requests to the application._ **The client will also keep track of cookies for us.** So yeah the two asserts are using different clients and thus different a different cookie - will write the answer up in a bit.

Comment: Alright that sounds good glad I can help, If need be ill write a answer myself in about an hour if you haven't done it by then

Comment: Alright i added the answer please accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im going to sum up the comments I made that gave the answer on how to solve this issue.

When creating a test app using Pytest and Flask there are a few different ways to go about it.

The suggested way to [create a test client](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/testing/) with proper app context is to use something like:

```
@pytest.fixture
def client():
    """ Creates the app from testconfig, activates test client and context then makes the db and allows the test client
    to be used """
app = create_app(TestConfig)

client = app.test_client()

ctx = app.app_context()
ctx.push()

db.create_all()


yield client

db.session.close()
db.drop_all() 
ctx.pop()
```

That creates  the client while pushing the app context so you can register things like your database and create the tables to the test client.

The second way is show in OP's question where use [app.test_request context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.test_request_context)

```
@pytest.fixture
def app():
    """An application for the tests."""
    _app = create_app(DevConfig)
    ctx = _app.test_request_context()
    ctx.push()

    yield _app

    ctx.pop()
```

and then create the test client in another pytest fixture

```
@pytest.fixture 
def client(app): 
   return app.test_client()
```

Creating a test client allows you to use various testing features and gives access to flask requests with the proper app context.